# Excel VBA with MS Access "Could not update; currently locked"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a VBA Application that connects with a MS Access database.

The program is designed so that each user has their own Excel File, which acts as a front-end to the back-end database. Multiple users can be using their Excel file at the same time, which means they both need to query the DB at the same time.

Recently a user got a message saying the DB "Could not update; currently locked". This is frustrating because I thought I fixed this problem earlier by taking many steps I thought would prevent this. Obviously something went wrong but I don't know what.

I wish I had a minimally reproducible example, but I'm really not sure what happened. This is the code that opens a database connection:

```
Public Function DBConnectToMSAccess() As Object

    Dim msg As String
    Dim accessCon As Object

    On Error GoTo ConnectError
    Dim accessFileLoc As String: accessFileLoc = ThisWorkbook.path & "\DB\GrabDB.accdb"
    Set accessCon = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    accessCon.Mode = 16 + 3 'adModeShareDenyNone + adModeReadWrite
    accessCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accessFileLoc
    
    'return the connection
    Set DBConnectToMSAccess = accessCon    
    Exit Function
    
ConnectError:

    If Not accessCon Is Nothing Then
        If accessCon.State = adStateOpen Then accessCon.Close
        Set accessCon = Nothing
    End If
    Set DBConnectToMSAccess = Nothing
    msg = "Could not connect to Access Database. Closing program."
    Call FORMSShowAlertForm(msg)
    Call UTILForceShutdown
    
End Function
```

After the connection is created, this next function queries the Database by passing an SQL query string as parameter. I indicated where the error must have been thrown. Then it looped 10 times and could not fix the problem, so the function "Failed"

```
Public Function MODQueryTable(accessQuery As String, ByRef accessCon) As Object

    Dim msg As String
    Dim accessRS As Object

    Set accessRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    accessRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient 
    accessRS.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    accessRS.LockType = adLockOptimistic 
    
    Dim retryCount As Integer: retryCount = 0
    On Error GoTo QueryFailed
    
    accessRS.Open accessQuery, accessCon  <------- ERROR IS HERE
    Set MODQueryTable = accessRS
    GoTo FxnEnd
    
QueryFailed:

    If retryCount < 10 And Err.Number = -2147467259 Then
        'ok database was locked
        'we'll just try again
        retryCount = retryCount + 1
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        On Error GoTo QueryFailed
        Resume
    Else
        msg = "Could not complete database query. Err.number=" & Err.Number & ", Err.description=" & Err.Description
        Call FORMSShowAlertForm(msg)
        Dim logMsg As String
        logMsg = "FAILED QUERYING DB, query=" & accessQuery & ", Err.number=" & Err.Number & ", Err.description=" & Err.Description
        Call UTILWriteWholeLogMsgToSeriousErrorsFile(logMsg)
        Set MODQueryTable = Nothing
        GoTo FxnEnd
    End If
    
FxnEnd:

    On Error Resume Next
    
End Function
```

As you can see in the second function, I tried to build-in protection against records being locked by just trying again a few times until it works. I figured if records are locked because another user happens to be mid-query, then that function should complete in a second or two at most. However, the user in this case just tried again 10 times and failed each time, leading to the error message.

These are other precautions I've taken to keep records from locking:

1. No persistent connections. You can see above DBConnectToMSAccess returns the connection object, and this is used locally within the caller (never a global variable). So I would hope connections are closed automatically at the end of each function. Even so, I also call this on each connection at the end of each function:

   > ```
   > Public Sub DBNormalCloseConn(ByRef accessCon As Object, ByVal ifCommit
   > As Boolean)
   >
   > Dim msg As String
   >
   > If dbTransactionInProcess Then
   >     On Error Resume Next
   >     If ifCommit Then
   >         'caller specified to commmit
   >         accessCon.CommitTrans
   >     Else
   >         'caller specified to rollback
   >         accessCon.RollbackTrans
   >     End If
   >     On Error GoTo 0
   >     dbTransactionInProcess = False
   > Else
   >     msg = "ERROR: UTILStopProcessing without transaction in process."
   > End If
   >
   > If Not accessCon Is Nothing Then
   >     If accessCon.State = adStateOpen Then accessCon.Close
   >     Set accessCon = Nothing
   > End If
   > If msg <> "" Then Call FORMSShowAlertForm(msg)
   >
   > End Sub
   > ```
2. All RecordSets are also local and are explicitly closed whenever I'm finished with them. This code is called within each function with each RecordSet to close.

   ```
   Public Sub DBCloseRS(ByRef accessRS As Object)

       If Not accessRS Is Nothing Then
           If accessRS.State = 1 Then accessRS.Close
       End If
       Set accessRS = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```

So my question is, what am I missing? Are the connection and recordset objects being initialized properly? Am I closing them properly? What likely went wrong, and is there something I could do to ensure this doesn't happen again? I am restricted to using MS Access.

Thanks for your help,
Geoff

Comment: By "VBA application" you mean code in Excel? Why use Excel as GUI? What line throws error? Disable error handler and step through code.

Comment: Did someone open the database in Access in exclusive mode before Excel could connect?

Comment: Yep its Excel VBA code with Excel as the GUI. I indicated the line that throws the error must be "accessRS.Open accessQuery, accessCon" in the second function shown. And If I step through the code, there are no errors. I can't replicate what the user experienced, but it 100% definitely happened. Hmmm its possible Access was opened as I was developing at the time, however another user was using the program at the same time with no problems. Would you say my coding approach is correct and it must have been something external like that?

Comment: I am not saying anything about your code approach, i just know from experience that Access locks the database when there is a design change. It's certainly simple enough to test... just start fresh, open the database in Access, then open a table in DESIGN MODE - then try to run the Excel code.

Comment: To add: Access does not automatically release the lock after the table design mode is closed. You would have to close Access to do that.

Comment: Ok thanks for your feedback. I'll do some further testing and see if I can learn more.

Comment: In the second block of code you do not try to reopen. You just loop to QueryFailed and nothing in between does anything with the connection, that will not retry anything. The label should at least be before "accessRS.Open"

Comment: @hennep I believe the Resume statement retries the line that failed, so the Resume statement triggers another retry, until the retry count is reached

Comment: I don't know how I could have missed that. Probably I misread "On Error GoTo QueryFailed" for "GoTo QueryFailed". I read somewhere on Microsoft.com that the same error number can be raised when the number of bits differs between Office and the driver. 64 bits Office and a 32 bits driver or  32 bits Office and a 64 bits driver. Something you might want to check.

Comment: Ah ok thanks I'll look into that as well. Appreciate your help